# Adding a where clause in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have very complicated query which fetches the last row of a table where the `invoicNo` is unique.I want to add a where clause to this query something like

```
WHERE bill_type LIKE '$invoice.
```

This is my current query

```
Select * From (SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM
 selected_items t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r order by rank DESC) si GROUP
 BY si.invoiceNo;
```

This is how my database looks
[image]

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you :)

Comment: Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: @bub it says page not found

Comment: @bub can you help with a solution I am new to mysql databases :) thanks

Comment: Maybe `WHERE bill_type = 'Invoice'` ?

Comment: Well I posted the tutorial link

Comment: @arkascha I know I just dont know where to place it in this query can you help.Thanks :)

Comment: If you know, then why did you post a "where clause" with an obvious syntax fault? I suggest you start reading the documentation. The link @bub gave above works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
  Select * From (SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM
    selected_items t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r order by rank DESC) si
     WHERE bill_type LIKE <Bill_type_value>
 GROUP BY si.invoiceNo;
```

Replace `<Bill_type_value>` accordingly

Comment: can you help me with this query SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM selected_items
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' GROUP BY invoiceNo; here I just want to access the last item in column sum_total.